# Turn pandas columns into JSON string

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe with columns col1, col2 and col3 and respective values. I would need to transform column names and values into a JSON string.

For instance, if the dataset is

```
data= pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['bravo', 'charlie','price'], 'col2': [1, 2, 3],'col3':['alpha','beta','gamma']})
```

I need to obtain an output like this

```
newdata= pd.DataFrame({'index': [0,1,2], 'payload': ['{"col1":"bravo", "col2":"1", "col3":"alpha"}', '{"col1":"charlie", "col2":"2", "col3":"beta"}', '{"col1":"price", "col2":"3", "col3":"gamma"}']})

I didn't find any function or iterative tool to perform this.

Thank you in advance!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If my understanding is correct, you want the index and the data records as a dict.

So:

```py
dict(index=list(data.index), payload=data.to_dict(orient='records'))
```

For your example data:

```
>>> import pprint
>>> pprint.pprint(dict(index=list(data.index), payload=data.to_dict(orient='records')))
{'index': [0, 1, 2],
 'payload': [{'col1': 'bravo', 'col2': 1, 'col3': 'alpha'},
             {'col1': 'charlie', 'col2': 2, 'col3': 'beta'},
             {'col1': 'price', 'col2': 3, 'col3': 'gamma'}]}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here you go:

```py
import pandas as pd

data= pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['bravo', 'charlie','price'], 'col2': [1, 2, 3],'col3':['alpha','beta','gamma']})
new_data = pd.DataFrame({
    'payload': data.to_dict(orient='records')
})
print(new_data)

## -- End pasted text --
                                          payload
0   {'col1': 'bravo', 'col2': 1, 'col3': 'alpha'}
1  {'col1': 'charlie', 'col2': 2, 'col3': 'beta'}
2   {'col1': 'price', 'col2': 3, 'col3': 'gamma'}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
df = data.agg(lambda s: dict(zip(s.index, s)), axis=1).rename('payload').to_frame()
```

Result:

```
# print(df)

                                          payload
0   {'col1': 'bravo', 'col2': 1, 'col3': 'alpha'}
1  {'col1': 'charlie', 'col2': 2, 'col3': 'beta'}
2   {'col1': 'price', 'col2': 3, 'col3': 'gamma'}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is one approach using `.to_dict('index')`.

**Ex:**

```
import pandas as pd

data= pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['bravo', 'charlie','price'], 'col2': [1, 2, 3],'col3':['alpha','beta','gamma']})
newdata = data.to_dict('index')
print({'index': list(newdata.keys()), 'payload': list(newdata.values())})
#OR -->newdata= pd.DataFrame({'index': list(newdata.keys()), 'payload': list(newdata.values())})
```

**Output:**

```
{'index': [0, 1, 2],
 'payload': [{'col1': 'bravo', 'col2': 1, 'col3': 'alpha'},
             {'col1': 'charlie', 'col2': 2, 'col3': 'beta'},
             {'col1': 'price', 'col2': 3, 'col3': 'gamma'}]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `to_dict`: `newdata = data.T.to_dict()`

```
>>> print(newdata.values())
[
  {'col2': 1, 'col3': 'alpha', 'col1': 'bravo'},
  {'col2': 2, 'col3': 'beta', 'col1': 'charlie'},
  {'col2': 3, 'col3': 'gamma', 'col1': 'price'}
]
```